# UART only working correctly one way (ATmega328p)

Tags: avr, uart

I got an Arduino Uno, which is driven by an ATmega328P. And I wanted to move away from its libraries and do everything on a *lower* level for learning purposes. However I cannot get the uart working correctly, it works now only when sending to the device. Receiving returns weird garbage wich the temrinal can't print.

```
#define BAUDRATE (((F_CPU / (BAUD * 16UL))) - 1)
void init_uart()
{
    UBRR0H = BAUDRATE >> 8; // set high baud
    UBRR0L = BAUDRATE; //set low baud
    UCSR0B = _BV(TXEN0) | _BV(RXEN0); //enable duplex
    UCSR0C = _BV(UCSZ00) | _BV(UCSZ01) | _BV(USBS0); //8-N-1
}

void putchar_uart(char c, FILE* stream)
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);   //wait till prev char is read
    UDR0 = c;
}

char getchar_uart(FILE* stream)
{
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, RXC0);    //wait if there is data
    return UDR0;
}

//^ actually is in a seperate file which gets linked

int main()
{
    DDRD |= PIN_LED;
    PORTD |= PIN_LED;

    stdout = &mystdout;
    stdin = &mystdin;

    char buf[0xFF];

    init_uart();
    while (1)
    {
        char c = getchar_uart(NULL);
        if (c == 'a')
        {
            PIND = PIN_LED;
            printf("%s\n", "Hallo");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and using minicom for the communication. Which is setup as: 115200 8N1 (with the correct serial device of course.)

It gets compiled as:

```
avr-gcc -Wall -Os -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL -DBAUD=115200 -std=c99 -L/home/joel/avr-libs/lib -I/home/joel/avr-libs/inc -o firmware.o main.c  -luart
```

So how do I know that one way works? Because of the led only toggles when typing in an 'a'. But the response are invalid characters. In hex:

```
c8 e1 ec ec ef 8a
```

Comment: You are basically receiving what you send, only with bit 7 erroneously set.  This may suggest a disagreement over the number of data bits or stop bits or parity.  Consider making a quick Arduino sketch which dumps the UART config register values for comparison with your settings.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I created a simple sketch which dumps all the registers I wrote to (including USCR0A), from that it wasn't anything special. The only difference is that Arduino sets the RXCIE, UDRIE bits on UCSR0B register and on the UCSR0A the U2X bit. So basically it uses interrupts and double mode, I'll test the double mode now if that works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the USBS bit you are commanding a second stop bit.

<strike>This appears to lead your computer to mistakenly believe that the MSB (which is the last data bit) is set when it isn't causing your received data to be OR'd with 0x80.</strike>

While this will cause a framing error, it is probably not the cause of the wrong MSB.  Your own answer about switching to 2x mode (and thus more accurately approximating the baud rate) is more key to the solution, though you should correct this too.

Comment: You are right I misunderstood the data sheet. Thanks alot :)

Comment: You definitely don't want USBS, but I'm not sure if it is this or baud rate error that was corrupting your data.

Comment: It also worked when enabling 2x mode, do you know why? Or was it coincidence?

Comment: That suggests maybe the real problem is a baud rate error (figure out what actual baud rate results from the integer divisors in each case), with the USBS merely causing a framing error which may be ignored.  I think you should undelete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem when Chris suggested to print out the config registers that Arduino uses I noticed that it uses the double mode. I couldn't configure that with minicom or I missed that. Maybe it is default to use such mode. Anyway it works now.

I also learned that avr-libc provides a header called util/setbaud.h which calculates the correct baud rate automatically. In the UBRRL_VALUE and UBRRH_VALUE fields.

Comment: Double mode is not a property of the serial word but rather a configuration of the UART.  It can lead to greater timing accuracy for certain clock/target baud situations.  I suppose it is possible a baud rate error could lead to the stop bit falling into the evaluation window for the MSB.

Comment: When I run the numbers the closest you can come in normal mode is 125kbaud, which I could see doing this.  2x mode gets you around 117.6 kbaud, a much better approximation.  So I think the mistaken MSB is probably due to baud error.